# React Native Android: Re-render screen every time it gets focus

Tags: android, react-native

I have tried to use the suggested methods like using the `forceUpdate()` method and setting state but i realised all these required first pressing a button. I also tried calling the `forceUpdate()` method from the constructor but this warns that the component has'nt yet rendered.
How can i automatically reload a screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react navigation, you could use a focus event listener when you revisit a screen:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

[Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)